# Can gcc's linker fold multiple instantiations of a static function in a C header into a single instance?

Tags: c, gcc, static, linker, header-files

The embedded C code I'm writing has numerous (i.e. >100) small static accessor functions defined in headers, but I'd be uncomfortable moving them out of the headers because the overall code clarity would suffer. :-(

Is gcc's linker smart enough to fold multiple instantiations of header-defined static functions into single instances within the final binary? More generally, do the C standards define linker behaviour for multiple identical instantiations of static functions defined in headers? Thanks!

To be precise: if static functions defined in headers refer to static data, then I can see that the linker would be unable to fold multiple instantiations together, because each function instance would refer to a different instance of that static data. However, where static functions defined in a header don't refer to static data, the compiled instantiations would be basically identical (bar the inevitable compiler static-naming kruft wrapped around them). Which is why I ask if gcc's linker is "smart" enough. :-)

Comment: There is a `-fipa-icf` option to perform "identical code folding". It is enabled by default for `-O2` and `-Os`. For it to work across compilation units, you will also need to use the `-flto` "link time optimization" option when compiling and linking.

Comment: Sounds like some bad design to me. Why do you have *static* accessor functions at all, if all including modules need them? Why don't you use public functions?

Comment: @thebusybee `static` in the sense of `static inline`. Pre-LTO, you don't get inlining for stuff from a different compilation unit. Only with LTO, `static` is reduced to pure semantic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gold and lld linkers perform identical code folding (so with some luck all local definitions will be coalesced) but GNU ld does not so the best approach would be to replace `static` with `inline` (duplicate `inline` definitions are guaranteed to be merged).